# Почему не компилируется JavaFX приложение?

Tags: java, javafx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Буду рад любым подсказкам! Спасибо.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe"     --add-modules     javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-    reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=64943:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\java\expert\bin;C:\java\expert\lib\javax.json-api-1.1.2.jar;C:\java\expert\lib\jFuzzyLogic_core.jar;C:\java\expert\lib\postgresql-42.1.4.jre7.jar;C:\java\expert\lib\javax.json-1.1.2.jar;C:\java\expert\lib\poi-3.9-20121203.jar;C:\java\expert\lib\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;C:\java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.web.jar -p C:\java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.graphics.jar org.tatasu.gtm.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x15269a9) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x15269a9
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
        at org.tatasu.gtm.Main.start(Main.java:14)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
... 1 more
Exception running application org.tatasu.gtm.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: лучше ошибку текстом опубликовать(не убирая скришота). Так как нет желания ручками набирать вашу ошибку в google

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте вывод терминала и ошибки скриншотами. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Другие люди с такой же ошибкой не смогут выйти на этот вопрос

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий Ок!

Comment: @gil9red Сделано!

Comment: @devoid пробовали сделать, то что описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/902648/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-javafx)?

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий Пробовал, получаю:
"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found"
У меня JDK 12, а JavaFX 11 - может быть тут проблема?

Answer (score 1):

**Запустил. Что я сделал**:

1. В RUN > Edit Configurations > VM options:

   --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"
   --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
   --add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.charts=ALL-UNNAMED
2. Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java compiler > Override compiler parameters:

   --add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.charts=ALL-UNNAMED
3. У меня JDK 11 и JavaFX 11